# Foreach: Group same data

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, kirby

I am attempting to group generated data from a foreach statement by date. I am using Kirby CMS but am having troubling accomplishing the following.

Goal (sudo):

```
date: 03/10/15
Take Over

date: 03/09/15
Video
Flash
Super GIF 2
Super GIF
Image
```

My Attempt:

```
date: 03/10/15
Take Over
date: 03/09/15
Video
date: 03/09/15
Flash
date: 03/09/15
Super GIF 2
date: 03/09/15
Super GIF
date: 03/09/15
Image
```

Code:

```
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($page->children()->visible()->sortBy('modified', 'desc')  as $projects): ?>
      <li>
        date: <?php echo $projects->modified('m/d/y') ?> <br>
        <a href="<?php echo $projects->url() ?>"><?php echo $projects->title()->html() ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach  ?>  
  </ul>
```

Second unsuccessful attempt:

```
  <ul>
      <?php foreach($page->children()->visible()->sortBy('modified', 'desc')  as $projects): ?>
       <li>
          <?php foreach($page->children()->visible()->sortBy('modified', 'desc')  as $project): ?>

            <?php 
              if($projects->modified('m/d/y') == $project->modified('m/d/y')) {
                echo $project->modified('m/d/y') . '<br>' . $project->title();
              }

            ?>

          <?php endforeach  ?>  
       </li>


    <?php endforeach  ?>  
  </ul>
```

Output:

```
03/10/15
Take Over
03/09/15
Video 03/09/15
Flash 03/09/15
Super GIF 2 03/09/15
Super GIF 03/09/15
Image
03/09/15
Video 03/09/15
Flash 03/09/15
Super GIF 2 03/09/15
Super GIF 03/09/15
Image
03/09/15
Video 03/09/15
Flash 03/09/15
Super GIF 2 03/09/15
Super GIF 03/09/15
Image
03/09/15
Video 03/09/15
Flash 03/09/15
Super GIF 2 03/09/15
Super GIF 03/09/15
Image
03/09/15
Video 03/09/15
Flash 03/09/15
Super GIF 2 03/09/15
Super GIF 03/09/15
Image
```

Comment: I think you need a nested foreach loop. Have you tried that approach ?

Comment: You just need to track the current date and when it changes from the last one echo it.  Just use an if to check and echo or not.

Comment: Updated with my attempt 2, its better but it should not repeat 03/09/15 that many times. just show once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable to hold the current date - `$currentDate`, then check if the `$projects->modified('m/d/y')` matches the `$currentDate` and if not, set it as the `$currentDate` and echo it-

```
  <?php $currentDate = ''; ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($page->children()->visible()->sortBy('modified', 'desc')  as $projects): ?>
      <li>
        <?php if($projects->modified('m/d/y') != $currentDate) { $currentDate = $projects->modified('m/d/y'); ?>
        date: <?php echo $projects->modified('m/d/y') ?> <br>
        <?php } ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $projects->url() ?>"><?php echo $projects->title()->html() ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach  ?>
```

**edited** - if you want the breaks between the dates, you can close/open the `<li>`/`</li>` inside the `if`

```
  <?php $currentDate = ''; ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($page->children()->visible()->sortBy('modified', 'desc')  as $projects): ?>
      <li>

        <?php if($projects->modified('m/d/y') != $currentDate) { 
            if($currentDate != '') { echo "</li><li>"; } // if not the 1st date, add a blank space/li before the next date 
            $currentDate = $projects->modified('m/d/y'); ?>
        date: <?php echo $projects->modified('m/d/y') ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <br><a href="<?php echo $projects->url() ?>"><?php echo $projects->title()->html() ?></a>

    <?php endforeach  ?>  
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: thanks, this is close but the grouping isnt working 100% properly, please take a look at the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/aD5pWGl.png?1 Everything below the second date, should be in the same `li` tag.

Comment: I have re-edited. You need to close/open the `<li>`s in the `if()` - `if($currentDate != '') { echo "</li><li>"; }` AND you need to move the last/final `</li>` to after the `<?php endforeach  ?>`.

Comment: no, it still didnt work correctly but I managed to fix it myself: https://jsfiddle.net/22fx4ew1/ thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you probably want to do is re-organize your list into containers.

** Note: all untested, but should be close **

This can be as simple as something like:

```
$containers = [];
foreach ($bar as $foo) {
  $containers[$foo['date']][] = $foo
}

ksort($containers);
```

If you're using PHP5.5+, you're in even more luck:

```
$containers = array_column($bar, null, 'date');
ksort($containers);
```

This should get you the structure you need for your looping:

```
$dates = array_keys($containers);
foreach ($dates as $container) {
  echo 'date: '.$container;
  var_dump($containers[$container]);
}
```